# How to obtain day of the month from day of the week?

Tags: python, date, math

I'm trying to get python to return the date of the month when a day of the week is inputed e.g:
1st Sunday of April 2018 returns 1
or 3rd Thursday of April 2018 returns 19

Are there python libraries or mathematical algorithms that do this? I've looked at Zeller's congruence but it seems like it does the opposite.

Comment: Find with [`date.weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) the weekday for the first of the month. Add value for difference in weekdays. Add 7*n for difference in weeks. Voila.

Comment: Damn how did I miss that. Thanks @MrT!

Comment: Most of the stuff you have to do with dates can be found in the `datetime` or (lesser known) `calendar` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Input string separating all the values and then takes all the dates of that day from that month in that year.

Here a big try :

```
import calendar
import re

c = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)

string = "1st Sunday of April 2018"
string.split().pop(2)
string_list = string.split()
year = int(string_list[4])
month = list(calendar.month_name).index(string_list[3])
day_num = list(calendar.day_name).index(string_list[1])
which = int(re.search(r'\d+', string_list[0]).group())

monthcal = c.monthdatescalendar(year,month)
date = [day for week in monthcal for day in week if \
            day.weekday() == day_num and \
            day.month == month][which-1]

print(date.day)
```